# Debugging HTTP Response code 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-8

I am new to ReSt APIs and working on a sample project wherein with Java8, Spring Boot and IDE is Intellij Idea. I am trying to make POST request with parameters as part of body in JSON format. This is my code:

```java
@PostMapping("/addEmployees")
public void addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    employeeController.addEmployee(dataForImport);
}
```

Employee Class is:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Dept")
    private String dept;
    @Column(name = "Manager")
    private String manager;
}
```

above code is followed by getters and setters.

Implementation of addEmployees() is as follows:

```java
public Employee addEmployees(Employee employee) {
    employeeRepo.save(employee);
    return employee;
}
```

employeeRepo is and object of Repository which is:

```java
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    @Query("some query")
    List<Employee> getReportees(@Param("manager")int manager);
    
    @Query("some query")
    List<Employee> somMethod(@Param("name")String name);
}
```

And the Body of the request is:

```json
{
    "name": "Abcd",
    "dept": "Clinical",
    "manager":"XYZX",
}
```

but upon execution is is responding as

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2023-02-28T09:12:31.653+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/company/addEmployees"
}
```

I wanted to know what I am missing or sending malformed data because of which it is sending this response.
Is there any way we can debug this or fetch more information so that we can figure what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the logs and the stacktrace thrown by your application. If you have IntelliJ the logs output should be in the panel **Run**

Comment: it is mot showing anything in Run Pane. Simply shows   this  .  "Spring"

 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

Comment: @moka We won't be able to help you without logs. Logs are the base for debugging issues. When you launched your application a panel should have open. There you can see lines of text scrolling

Answer (score 0):

The original post has 3 misspellings in the code. Please correct them first.

It should be probably:

```
@PostMapping("/company/addEmployees")
public void addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    employeeController.addEmployees(employee);
}
```